# Use algebra to write an equation of a circle that contains 3 points

Tags: geometry

Use algebra to write an equation of the circle that contains the following set of points: (2,1), (-3,-4), and (4,-4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2-h)^2+(1-k)^2=r^2 \   (1)$$
$$(-3-h)^2+(-4-k)^2=r^2 \  (2)$$
$$(4-h)^2+(-4-k)^2=r^2 \   (3)$$

Three equations, three variables.

$(3)-(2)$:

$$(4-h)^2=(3+h)^2$$
$$(3+h-4+h)(3+h+4-h)=0$$
$$h=\frac{1}{2}$$

$(1)-(2)$:

$$(2-h)^2-(-3-h)^2+(1-k)^2-(-4-k)^2=0$$
$$(2-h)^2-(3+h)^2+(1-k)^2-(4+k)^2=0$$
$$(2-h-3-h)(2-h+3+h)+(1-k-4-k)(1-k+4+k)=0$$
$$(-1-2h)5+(-3-2k)5=0$$
$$4+2h+2k=0$$
$$k=\frac{-5}{2}$$

Replacing:

$$\left(2-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{-5}{2}\right)^2=r^2$$ 
$$r=\sqrt{\frac{29}{2}}$$

Or following the kike0001 advice, you could replace in the general equation of the circle:

$$x^2+y^2 +Dx +Ey+F=0$$

Replacing with lead:

$$5+2D+1E+F=0$$
$$25-3D-4E+F=0$$
$$32+4D-4E+F=0$$

With solution:
$$D=-1$$
$$E=5$$
$$F=-8$$

Answer (score 1):

Is more easy work with the general ecuation of the circunference $$x^2+y^2 +Dx +Ey+F=0$$ then the replacement for the points $(2,1)$, $(-3,-4)$, and $(4,-4)$ for obtain a system $3\times3$ of linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{vmatrix}
x^2+y^2&x&y&1\\
2^2+1^2&2&1&1\\
(-3)^2+(-4)^2&-3&-4&1\\
4^2+(-4)^2&4&-4&1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=0$